# Use browser form validation without submission (JS / Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, submit

I am working on a multi part form that is composed of three views.
The user will have to fill the first part, click next, fill the second part, next again, the third part and finally submit the form.

However I would like to add validation to each part to ensure the user have filled all required fields before reaching the next part.
For simplicity and consistency with the rest of the website I would like to use the browser validation system, which is triggered at form submission by default.

Is there any way to use callback that detect invalid fields and highlight them when the form is submitted without a call to `submit` ?

Comment: Most probably you have three different forms in same page?? then try to submit  the form using jquery .submit();

Comment: No, I have a single form for the three parts, this is not by choice but imposed by the back-end.